# python django converting date values in months or days

Tags: python, django, date

Suppose I have two dates.. date1 and date2
I want to subtract date2 from date1 and whatever comes the result I want to convert it in date..
Like:

```
if (date_1 - date2) > 4 months
```

Here how can I convert the resultant date into months or you can say in days..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: use python datetimes    `print (datetime1-datetime2).days`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for relative dates, you can use one of two approaches:

```
import datetime

if d2 - datetime.timedelta(days= 4*365./12) > d1:
    # the difference is greater than 4 months.
```

If you need more accurate day conversions, you can use the `relativedelta` in `dateutil` module.

Example

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

if d2 - relativedelta(months=4) > d1:
    #The diff is greater than 4 months.
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 2, 13, 35, 39, 975914)
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 2, 13, 0, 0, 0)
>>> d1 - datetime.timedelta(days=4*365./12) > d2
True

>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> d1 - relativedelta(month=4)
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 2, 13, 35, 44, 735993)
>>> d1 - relativedelta(month=4) > d2
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Subtraction of two dates returns a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object:

```
>>> print (data1 - date2).days
```

> A `timedelta` object represents a duration, the difference between two dates or times